# Schema para mi sitio Web (no es wordpress)

Tags: html, asp.net, seo

quiero implementar Schema org Games en mi pagina web, parar mejorar mi posicion en google (SEO) y agregale esas famosas "estrellitas amarillas".

Pero no llego a entender bien donde debo colocar los TAG's de Schema.
Por ejemplo un Schema que encontre podria ser asi:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span property="brand">Nombre de la marca</span>
<span property="name">Nombre del producto</span>
<img property="image" src="url_producto.jpg" alt="Logo + Nombre del producto" />
<span property="description">Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto Describe aquí el producto
</span>
</div>
```

Mi duda es a donde va ese div?

Si tengo que colocarlo en el HEAD de mi Index pagina, o en el BODYde la Index?

O debo colocarlo en cada una de mis paginas?